# Goalseeking Dependent variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a scenario where I have two types of buses which we will call bus group A and bus group B. Bus group A has 10 buses whilst bus group B has 100 buses.

Assume all buses in A each travel the same X KM's per annum and all buses in B each travel the same y km's per annum.

Total KM's travelled in the year for all buses was 10,000,000 KMs. If a bus in A travels 75% of the distance of a bus in B:

1. how many km's would a bus in Group A travel in a year
2. how many km's would a bus in Group B travel in a year

What is the formula to work out this problem presented in a way I could apply it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

- Number of Buses in Group A = A
- Number of Buses in Group B = B
- Total KM's = 10,000,000
- Ratio of kms travelled between A and B = W
- Total KM's traveled by a Bus in Group B = (10,000,000 / (1 + (W / (B/A)))) / B
- Total KM's traveled by Bus in Group A = W * Group B Bus KM

I don't have a clue how to solve for three bus groups where two groups are a % of a third one but this answers my own question.